# Replace pipe character with '</td><td>' in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a nested unordered list which I have to convert to a table with jQuery. I managed to replace the following:

UL -> TABLE

LI -> TD

But now I have to search and replace the '|' characters to '`</td><td>`'. But I don't understand how this can be done.

```js
$('.wd-widget > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li').each( function() {
    $(this).replaceWith( function() {
        return $('<tr><td>' + this.innerHTML + '</td></tr>');
    });
});

$('.wd-widget > ul > li > ul > li > ul').each( function() {
    $(this).replaceWith( function() {
        return $('<table>' + this.innerHTML + '</table>')
    })
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wd-widget">
  <ul>    
    <li><a href="#">label</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">13:30 - 14:15|13:30 - 14:15</a>
          <ul>
          <li>2018|september|inschrijven</li>
          <li>2019|mei|inschrijven</li>
          <li>2020|januari|inschrijven</li>
          <li>2020|augustus-september|inschrijven</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Given the input you have provided us, what is the expected output?

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. I've came up with a solution myself. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reg exp to replace pipe like:

```js
$('.wd-widget > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li').each( function() {
    $(this).replaceWith( function() {
        return $('<tr><td>' + this.innerText.replace(/\|/g, '###') + '</td></tr>');
    });
});

$('.wd-widget > ul > li > ul > li > ul').each( function() {
    $(this).replaceWith( function() {
        return $('<table>' + this.innerHTML + '</table>')
    })
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wd-widget">
  <ul>    
    <li><a href="#">label</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">13:30 - 14:15|13:30 - 14:15</a>
          <ul>
          <li>2018|september|inschrijven</li>
          <li>2019|mei|inschrijven</li>
          <li>2020|januari|inschrijven</li>
          <li>2020|augustus-september|inschrijven</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Few minutes after posting this question I came up with this idea. :/

```
$('.wd-widget td').each( function() {
  $(this).replaceWith( function() {
     var newInnerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/\|/g, "</td><td>");
     return $('<td>' + newInnerHTML + '</td>');
  });
});
```

And it works. :) This way I converted all the pipe-characters to a separate table cell.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't replace. I'd split the content based on your separator and work from there

```js
$('.wd-widget > ul > li > ul > li > ul').each( function() {
    $(this).replaceWith( function() {
        var rows =  ""
        $(this).find("li").each(function(){
                      var cells = "<td>" + $(this).html().split("|").join("</td><td>") + "</td>";
                      rows +="<tr>" + cells + "</tr>";
        });
        
        console.log(rows);
        return $('<table>' + rows + '</table>')
    })
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wd-widget">
  <ul>    
    <li><a href="#">label</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">13:30 - 14:15|13:30 - 14:15</a>
          <ul>
          <li>2018|september|inschrijven</li>
          <li>2019|mei|inschrijven</li>
          <li>2020|januari|inschrijven</li>
          <li>2020|augustus-september|inschrijven</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```